# Regular Expression - minus/hyphen character issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, httpd.conf

I have a url that contains the following

```
/4-new-south-wales/499-some-category.html
```

I would like to remove using mod_rewrite the numeric and the following hyphen.

I have the following rule

```
RewriteRule (.*)\d+-(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Which gives me the following

```
/4-new-south-wales-nsw/49cross-breeds-designer-dogs.html
```

These may be nested at any level. eg

```
/a/b/c/4-new-south-wales-nsw/49123123-cross-breeds-designer-dogs.html
```

I would like to end up with

```
/a/b/c/new-south-wales-nsw/cross-breeds-designer-dogs.html
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where's the question here? Please tell us exactly what you need the rewite rule to do.

Comment: Hi, I would like the rewrite rule to "remove using mod_rewrite the numeric and the following hyphen"

Comment: What exactly should be the result? `/new-south-wales-nsw/cross-breeds-designer-dogs.html` ? So one replacement or two? May there be more?

Comment: I would like to remove the numberic- 4- and 499-  Cheers.  yes morja - that is the result I would like, although it may be /a/b/c/new-south-wales-nsw/cross-breeds-designer-dogs.html  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule (.*?)\d+-(.*?)\d+-(.*) $1$2$3 [R=301,L]
```

The `?` makes the pattern ungreedy.

See and test on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/2QF0dotIAx)

Comment: Thanks morja - some of the urls have only a single numeric- combination while others have two.  I used RewriteRule (.*?)\d+-(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L] which is working.  So I needed the ungreedy for the first group

Answer (score 1):

```
(/.*/)\d+-(.*)
```

Will this fix it?

The .* is greedy, so it'll match the first numeric characters too, leaving only the last digit to be matched by the \d+, so your first capture group ends up being: 
/4-new-south-wales/49

Comment: Hi Pcaclcao,  I tested your regex and it removed the nested levels so the result removed the /a/b/c in my post edit.

Comment: I didn't set up Apache to test this, but using a regular text editor and applying the replace with my regex to: /a/b/c/4-new-south-wales-nsw/49123123-cross-breeds-designer-dogs.html gives me: /a/b/c/4-new-south-wales-nsw/cross-breeds-designer-dogs.html Isn't this what you need?

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear.  I would like to remove the numeric and the trailing hyphen.  eg.  remove the 4- and the 499- from the provided url.  I have tested my solution in a regex editor which works however when I apply same regex to .htaccess I get the issue above where the hyphen and a single numeric digit disappears.

Comment: you're answer worked with the following adjustnemt: RewriteRule (.*/)\d+-(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L].  I understand that my question was not clear enough - can I accept you both?

Comment: Unfortunatly no :) Choose one and upvote the other/both. We won't be mad, promise!

Comment: I would upvote however I do not have enough reputation - I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

To replace multiple, arbitrarily placed occurrences of the `/ddd-XXX` pattern within the URL path, Apache needs to replace each occurrence one at a time, and then redirect the URL recursively after each replacement. But to do this correctly, you'll need to add the `RewriteBase` statement to the `.htaccess` file, and set it to the path containing the `.htaccess` file.

Here is a tested `.htaccess` file which does what you are looking for:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Set RewriteBase to the URL-path containing this .htaccess file:
    RewriteBase /apache

    # Redirect first "/ddd-XXX" path segment to: "/XXX":
    RewriteRule ^((?:(?!\d+-)[^/]+/)*)\d+-(.*)$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

    # Rewrite the resulting URL path to show.php as a query string
    # (if resulting URL-path is NOT a real file or a directory).
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ show.php?path=$1

</IfModule>
```

On my test system, this `.htaccess` file is located in the `/apache` directory (which is what I have set the `RewriteBase` to). Note that the final redirected URL path may not be a real file! In the `.htaccess` file above, I have an additional rule which handles the final redirected URL (which does not point to a real file), and passes this path as a query variable to a `show.php` script.